# ember-data: Loading hasMany association on demand

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ember.js, ember-data

(Updated for ember-data API Rev 11...)

## TL;DR

What is the right way to use <strike>`DS.Adapter.findAssociation(...)`</strike>`DS.Adapter.findHasMany(...)` to load `hasMany` associations on demand? Especially, once you load child records, how do you deal with the fact that re-loading the parent record from the server empties the hasMany array? I do *not* want to (perhaps can't) include the id's of the child records in an array in the parent. Or is there another way to do this that I'm missing?

As a side note, I'm confused about what options should be passed in a `hasMany`/`belongsTo` definition for key linkage (and am I supposed to use mappings if I have no sideloaded data or array of ids?), so if you think my problem could lie in my association definition, there's a good chance you're right.

## Long version

I am writing my own subclass of `DS.RESTAdapter` to tie ember-data to an ASP.NET WebAPI backend (using Entity Framework). So far so good, but I'm having a heck of a time getting associations to work right.

Similar to [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364734/emberjs-data-how-to-load-hasmany-data-later), I noticed that ember-data's front page <strike>says</strike> *used* to say that if you have a `hasMany` association in your model, and you `get` that property, the store will issue a request for the child records. Quoting from the page:

> If you were to request the profile, like this:
>
> ```
> author.get('profile');
> ```
>
> …the REST adapter would send a request to the URL /profiles?author_id=1.

The implication is this is what happens if you don't sideload and don't include an array of ids. I realize that these docs are somewhat out of date, but I haven't been able to make this happen, either in API version 7 or more recently version 9. However <strike>in version 9 I did find the `findAssociation` method,</strike> in version 11 there is the `findHasMany` method, which I'm guessing is what might have been used to make this happen, and which I'm now trying to use.

### Why not include an array of ids or sideload?

Three main reasons I don't want to do this (and possibly can't):

1. It's not obvious how to do either of these things with ASP.NET WebAPI, at least not with the simple decoration-based approach I'm using. And, I really like the simplicity and thinness of the backend right now, with EF and WebAPI it's almost entirely boilerplate for each entity and I'm done! I even get OData filtering support "free".
2. My child records will often be generated via expensive queries (aggregates...metrics rollups, for instance). And there are lots of different classes of child entities for a single parent entity. So even getting the ids for *all* the child types would be expensive, and generating and sideloading all the child records are out of the question.
3. I have child entities where the primary key is a composite key. I haven't seen an example of this even being supported/possible in ember-data, at least not for dealing with associations (e.g. how would you do an array of ids?). I made a computed property in my client-side model that coerces the composite key into a single string, so I can retrieve a single record from the store using `find(...)`, but again I have no idea how this would even work with an association.

### Trying to use <strike>`findAssociation`</strike>`findHasMany`

I've figured out that in API version <strike>9 (and some earlier versions but not all?)</strike> 11, I can perhaps implement the <strike>`DS.Adapter.findAssociation`</strike> `DS.Adapter.findHasMany` method to retrieve the child records of a `hasMany` association. This mostly works, but requires some gymnastics. Here is my generalized <strike>`findAssociation`</strike> `findHasMany` method:

```js
findHasMany: function (store, record, relationship, ids) {

    var adapter = this;
    var root = this.rootForType(relationship.type);
    var query = relationship.options.query(record);

    var hits = store.findQuery(relationship.type, query);

    hits.on('didLoad', function () {
        // NOTE: This MUST happen in the callback, because findHasMany is in
        // the execution path for record.get(relationship.key)!!! Otherwise causes
        // infinite loop!!!
        var arrMany = record.get(relationship.key);

        if (hits.get('isLoaded')) {
            arrMany.loadingRecordsCount = 1 + hits.get('length') + (typeof arrMany.loadingRecordsCount == "number" ? arrMany.loadingRecordsCount : 0);
            hits.forEach(function (item, index, enumerable) {
                arrMany.addToContent(item);
                arrMany.loadedRecord();
            });
            arrMany.loadedRecord(); // weird, but this and the "1 +" above make sure isLoaded/didLoad fires even if there were zero results.
        }
    });

}
```

To make this work, my `hasMany` definitions set a `query` option value which is a function on the record that returns a hash of parameters for the query string in the request for the children. Since this is for a ASP.NET WebAPI backend, this will probably be an OData filter, e.g.:

```js
App.ParentEntity = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    children: DS.hasMany('App.ChildEntity', {
        query: function (record) {
            return {
                "$filter": "ChildForeignKey eq '" + record.get('id') + "'"
            };
        }
    })
});
```

One of the tricks is adding the items to the `ManyArray` using `addToContent(item)`, so that the parent record doesn't get marked "dirty" as if it has been edited. The other is, when I retrieve the JSON for the parent record initially, I have to manually set a value of `true` for the association name's key (the JSON coming from the server does not have the key at all). I.e.:

```js
    var a = Ember.isArray(json) ? json : [json];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        type.eachAssociation(function (key) {
            var meta = type.metaForProperty(key);
            a[i][key] = true;
        });
    }
```

This sounds nuts, but this is why: If you look at the implementation of `DS.Store.findMany` and find where <strike>`findAssociation`</strike> `findHasMany` is called, you'll find:

```js
findMany: function(type, ids, record, relationship){
...
if (!Ember.isArray(ids)) {
  var adapter = this.adapterForType(type);
  if (adapter && adapter.findHasMany) { adapter.findHasMany(this, record, relationship, ids); }
  else { throw fmt("Adapter is either null or does not implement `findMany` method", this); }

  return this.createManyArray(type, Ember.A());
}
```

And if you look at this line from the ember-data internal function <strike>`hasAssociation`</strike> `hasRelationship` where `findMany` is called, you'll see what is passed for the 2nd parameter:

```
relationship = store.findMany(type, ids || [], this, meta);
```

So, the only way to get <strike>`findAssociation`</strike> `findHasMany` to be called is to have the value in the JSON be something that is "truthy", but is *not* an Array--I use `true`. I'm thinking this is either a bug/incomplete, or an indication that I'm on the wrong track--if someone could tell me which that would be great too.

With all that, I can get ember-data to automatically issue a request to the server for the child records, e.g. to `http://myserver.net/api/child_entity/$filter=ChildForeignKey eq '42'` and it works--the child records get loaded, and they get associated with the parent record (incidentally, the inverse `belongsTo` relationship gets populated properly too, despite the fact that I'm not explicitly touching it--I have no idea where or how that is happening).

But that breaks down pretty quickly if I don't stop there.

### Dealing with reloading the parent record

So say I successfully load up the child records into a parent record, but then navigate to a place where *all* the parent records are retrieved (to populate a menu). Since the newly loaded parent records have no array of ids and nothing is sideloaded, the parent record is refreshed without any children again! Worse, the `ManyArray`'s `isLoaded` property remains `true`! So I can't even observe anything to re-load the children.

So if I simultaneously have a view onscreen displaying the child values, it immediately zaps to having no child record values. Or if I navigate back to one, when `App.store.find('App.ParentEntity', 42)` is called, the record is loaded from the store without a request to the server, and of course it has no child records.

This is hint #2 that I probably am going about this the wrong way. So...what is the right way to load child records on demand?

Thanks much!

Comment: Why not include an array of ids or sideload? #4: I'm using a 3rd party API with JSONP and have no control over their output format.

Comment: Of note, the latest versions of ember-data rename `hasAssociation` to `hasFindMany`, and may address the "dirty record" issue with new adapter hooks such as `dirtyRecordsForHasManyChange`, but the fundamental question of how to do this is still relevant. I do have a [simpler version of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382538/ember-data-how-to-use-ds-adapter-findhasmany) asked with the updated language, but this question with the more specific conditions is still valid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the latest Ember Data (as of Jan 25th 2013)... here's my solution to lazy loading hasMany relationships. I modifed `DS.hasMany` and added a method to `DS.Adapter`.

I changed two lines in `DS.hasMany`:

```
DS.hasMany = function(type, options) {
  Ember.assert("The type passed to DS.hasMany must be defined", !!type);
  return (function(type, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var meta = { type: type, isRelationship: true, options: options, kind: 'hasMany' };
    return Ember.computed(function(key, value) {
      var data = get(this, 'data').hasMany,
          store = get(this, 'store'),
          ids, relationship;

      if (typeof type === 'string') {
        type = get(this, type, false) || get(Ember.lookup, type);
      }

      meta.key = key;
      ids = data[key];
      relationship = store.findMany(type, ids, this, meta);
      set(relationship, 'owner', this);
      set(relationship, 'name', key);
      return relationship;
    }).property().meta(meta);
  })(type, options);

};
```

First, I added the `key` to the `meta` object...

```
meta.key = key;
```

...and second, as previously noted above, I removed the empty array from the `findMany` call by changing...

```
relationship = store.findMany(type, ids || [], this, meta);
```

...to...

```
relationship = store.findMany(type, ids, this, meta);
```

...allowing `ids` to be passed in to `findMany` as `undefined`.

Next, I added a `didFindHasMany` hook to `DS.Adapter`:

```
DS.Adapter.reopen({

  /**
   Loads the response to a request for records by findHasMany.

   Your adapter should call this method from its `findHasMany`
   method with the response from the backend.

   @param {DS.Store} store
   @param {subclass of DS.Model} type
   @param {any} payload
   @param {subclass of DS.Model} record the record of which the relationship is a member (parent record)
   @param {String} key the property name of the relationship on the parent record
   */
  didFindHasMany: function(store, type, payload, record, key) {

    var loader = DS.loaderFor(store);

    loader.populateArray = function(references) {
      store.loadHasMany(record, key, references.map(function(reference) { return reference.id; }));
    };

    get(this, 'serializer').extractMany(loader, payload, type);
  }

});
```

I modeled this after the `DS.Adapter`'s `didFindQuery` hook using the `loadHasMany` that I found already implemented on the `DS.Store`. Then in my custom adapter I implemented a `findHasMany` method that uses the following code in its success callback:

```
Ember.run(this, function() {
  adapter.didFindHasMany(store, type, response.data, record, key);
});
```

I haven't tested this extensively but it seems to be working correctly. Looking through recent modifications made to ember-data's code, it seems to me that they have slowly been moving in a direction in which something similar to this approach will be supported at some point in the future. Or at the very least that's my hope.

Comment: So there's no way to do it without modifying Ember Data?

Comment: From what I can tell... Not yet.

Comment: that's a serious bummer. Still, it ain't your fault, and you went through a lot of trouble. So, I'm accepting this and opening up an issue on their GitHub page. thanks!

Comment: Hmm, a rather auspicious issue number... https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/666

Comment: Thanks Mike, while I'm also not thrilled with the fact that it requires a patch, it's probably the best answer I'm going to get--and you've certainly put in the effort. If you put a link to this answer in on [my other closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382538/ember-data-how-to-use-ds-adapter-findhasmany) I'll give you credit for answering that one as well. One suggestion, rather than patching the Ember Data file directly, couldn't you override `DS.hasMany` with `.reopenClass` instead of patching the original file to make it a little cleaner?

Comment: Here is a github pull request with the related changes from above: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/672