# Possible to cause a `hasMany` property to refresh on next `get`?

Tags: ember-data

This is in the context of loading the `hasMany` from a string URL, [as discussed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382538/ember-data-how-to-use-ds-adapter-findhasmany), but there may be other use cases.

My situation is: I have a record with a `hasMany` relationship loaded via an "opaque" string (URL, i.e. *not* an array of ids), the contents of which is then requested on demand. Subsequently, if the parent record is reloaded the URL string is again populated into the `data` hash for the model object. In this case, I want to be able to "reset" the `hasMany` relationship/property, such that the next time the property is accessed (and not before then) it will re-request the child record data from the server.

However, I can't find a remotely good way to do this. The code that kicks off the request initially (a call to `DS.Store.findMany()`) is embedded in the `get` code of the computed property that Ember Data creates for the `hasMany`. So, I could theoretically delete the cache for the property and send the necessary change events to cause the `get` method code to be run again. However, that code actually *creates* the `DS.ManyArray` using the store's `recordArrayManager` which retains references to the created array. So re-executing the `get` code would necessarily create a new `DS.ManyArray`, which seems inefficient. Furthermore, removing the "old" array from the `recordArrayManager` is complex because it links the array to each reference for each object that's in the array. I suppose if I first remove everything from the array this might fix this, but also might have other side effects.

Any better ideas for how to deal with this scenario?