# ember.js rest api with pagination

Tags: pagination, ember.js, ember-data

At the moment I'm pointless how do achieve pagination with ember-data. I found out, that i can return 'meta' property in response and ember-data does not throw an error. But I just don't know how to access it, nor what is intended purpose of this property.

The few examples on internet assume that i have whole collection already loaded to ember, or they do little trick and do infinite scroll, which does'nt require information about page count.

I think that loading all records it's ok if I would have < 1k of them, but sometimes I'll be dealing with massive amounts of data (let's say apache logs). What then?

So basically I'm at the point in which I would like to use ember and ember-data to build my first real-life application, but I just think that it is not a good idea.

Ok, so anybody has any idea how to solve this basic, yet complicated, problem? :)

Comment: Are you using RC1 and ember-data rev 11? Also what adapter are you using with it? What server backend do you have? Do you need each page to respect history and the back button?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699796/ember-data-loading-hasmany-association-on-demand/14532845#14532845). There is some [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/666) on the github tracker as well.

Comment: @Toran Billups: all latest taken from github repos.

Comment: as for backend: it's simple solution based on [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/). History and back button would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here are some ideas to get you started.

First, you have to start with a route and take an page number as a dynamic parameter.

```
this.resource('posts', { path: '/posts/:page' };
```

Then as I have no experience with Silex, you need to support some kind of server side parameters that could be used for pagination. For example `offset` and `limit` where first means how many records you want to skip and second how many record you want in select from there. Ideally you should implement them as query parameters like `?offset=0&limit=10`.

Then you just implement your table route as follows:

```
App.TableRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return App.Post.find({ offset: (params.page - 1) * 10, limit: 10  });
    }
});
```

You can then start doing some more magic and create your items per page parameter or validate the page number by fetching number of all records in advance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I switched to angular.js. In my opinion it's much better than Ember.js - everything is nicely testable with karma runner and jasmine.